# Erro ao exportar componente personalizado

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routes, componentes, exportação

Estou trabalhando com Angular, e num template pro que comprei. Contudo estou tentando exportar um componente personalizado, mas não obtive êxito, ao tentar exportar esse meu componente, o fiz igualmente aos exemplos do próprio template que comprei e estou usando, no entanto me apresentam os seguintes erro:

> ERROR in src/app/pages/apps/propositions/propositions.component.html:12:5 - error NG8001: 'cui-search-filter-propositions-component' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'cui-search-filter-propositions-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'cui-search-filter-propositions-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>    12     **

Já busquei soluções na internet, até aqui mesmo no stackoverflow, contudo nenhuma delas se aplicou como solução ao meu caso. Haja vista que geralmente, na grande maioria das soluções propostas em fóruns da internet ou não se aplicam ao meu caso, ou eu já estou aplicando o sugerido.

Segue o código:

```
-> CLASSE DO COMPONENTE

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { NodeBackend } from 'src/app/services/backend/nodeBackend'
import { NzNotificationService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/notification'

@Component({
  selector: 'cui-search-filter-propositions-component',
  templateUrl: './searchFilterPropositions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchFilterPropositions.component.scss'],
  providers: [NodeBackend],
})
export class SearchFilterPropositionsComponent implements OnInit {
```

---

```
--> MÓDULO ONDE FAÇO A EXPORTAÇÃO DA CLASSE DO COMPONENTE

import { SearchFilterPropositionsComponent } from 
'./SearchFilterPropositions/searchFilterPropositions.component' **<-- IMPORT AQUI**

const COMPONENTS = [
  TopbarComponent,
  TopbarIssuesHistoryComponent,
  TopbarSearchComponent,
  TopbarUserMenuComponent,
  TopbarProjectManagementComponent,
  TopbarActionsComponent,
  TopbarLanguageSwitcherComponent,
  MenuLeftComponent,
  MenuTopComponent,
  FooterComponent,
  BreadcrumbsComponent,
  SidebarComponent,
  SupportChatComponent,
  TopbarFavPagesComponent,
  IconsSidebarComponent,
  SearchFilterPropositionsComponent, **<-- COMPONENTE**
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    WidgetsComponentsModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS],
  exports: [...COMPONENTS], **<-- EXPORT AQUI COM OS DEMIAS COMPONENTES**
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

---

```
--> ONDE O MÓDULO DO LAYOUT ESTÁ SENDO EXPORTADO (MÓDULO QUE CONTÉM O COMPONENTE)

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { SharedModule } from '../shared.module'
import { LayoutModule } from '../components/cleanui/layout/layout.module' **<-- IMPORT AQUI**

import { LayoutAuthComponent } from './Auth/auth.component'
import { LayoutMainComponent } from './Main/main.component'
import { LayoutPublicComponent } from './Public/public.component'

const COMPONENTS = [LayoutAuthComponent, LayoutMainComponent, LayoutPublicComponent]

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule, LayoutModule], **<-- MÓDULO LAYOUT AQUI**
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS],
  exports: [...COMPONENTS],
})
export class LayoutsModule {}
```

---

```
--> AQUI O APP ROUTING MODULE

import { LayoutsModule } from 'src/app/layouts/layouts.module' **<-- IMPORT DO MÓDULO**

// layouts & notfound
import { LayoutAuthComponent } from 'src/app/layouts/Auth/auth.component'
import { LayoutMainComponent } from 'src/app/layouts/Main/main.component'

{ CÓDIGO ABREVIADO }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      preloadingStrategy: AppPreloader,
    }),
    LayoutsModule, **<-- MÓDULO AQUI**
  ],
  providers: [AppPreloader],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, acredito que seja onde você ta importando o LayoutsModule.

Pelo que vi no último bloco de código, ta tentando importar ele no `AppRoutingModule`, quando deveria importar ele no `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer essa importação do módulo do Layout em dois possíveis lugares:

No módulo da sua página, caso você utilize LazyLoad, ou no módulo AppModule, caso esteja utilizando roteamento padrão.

Importar no AppRouting não irá funcionar pois não é lá que é gerenciado esse tipo de informação. Componentes sempre estão ligados a um módulo principal, e esse módulo está ligado a uma rota.

Se o seu LayoutModule não é um módulo completo, incluindo os componentes página e não está sendo usado como LazyLoad, ele não irá funcionar de maneira independente e irá dar erro pois ele nunca está sendo importado pelo módulo que está gerenciando o componente da rota atual.